# Installing SKPM (Sketch Plugin Manager) via npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, skpm

I've been attempting to install a npm package, which has been throwing a bunch of errors which I'm not too familiar with. **Keep in mind that these errors are after executing `sudo npm install -g skpm`**:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/skpm/node_modules/keytar/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/skpm/node_modules/keytar
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keytar@4.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the keytar@4.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/USERNAME/.npm/_logs/2017-12-19T01_53_44_910Z-debug.log
```

Originally I'd thought that I needed to install keytar to make this work, but after installing I still had the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue as to why skpm was not installing.

**Make sure you install x-code + command line tools access**

This fixed the issue and SKPM installed.

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid use `sudo npm -g install`**
During gyp compilation you will have such problems again and again.
Fixing permissions is the solution.

Quote from [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions):

> You can fix this problem using one of three options:
>
> 1. Change the permission to npm's default directory.
> 2. Change npm's default directory to another directory.
> 3. Install Node with a package manager that takes care of this for you. You should back-up your computer before moving forward.
>
> **Option 1: Change the permission to npm's default directory**
>
> Find the path to npm's directory: `npm config get prefix` For many systems, this will be `/usr/local`.
>
> WARNING: If the displayed path is just `/usr`, switch to Option 2 or you
>   will mess up your permissions.
>
> Change the owner of npm's directories to the name of the current user
>   (your username!):
>
> `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`
>
> This changes the permissions of the sub-folders used by npm and some other tools (lib/node_modules, bin, and share).
>
> **Option 2: Change npm's default directory to another directory**
>
> There are times when you do not want to change ownership of the
>   default directory that npm uses (i.e. /usr) as this could cause some
>   problems, for example if you are sharing the system with other users.
>
> Instead, you can configure npm to use a different directory
>   altogether. In our case, this will be a hidden directory in our home
>   folder.
>
> Make a directory for global installations:
>
> `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
>
> Configure npm to use the new directory path:
>
> `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
>
> Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
>
> `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
>
> Back on the command line, update your system variables:
>
> `source ~/.profile`
>
> Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.
>
> `npm install -g jshint`
>
> Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify `~/.profile`):
>
> `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global`
>
> **Option 3**: Use a package manager that takes care of this for you.
>
> If you're doing a fresh install of Node on Mac OS, you can avoid this
>   problem altogether by using the Homebrew package manager. Homebrew
>   sets things up out of the box with the correct permissions.
>
> `brew install node`

Answer (score 1):

usually `EACCES: permission denied` occurs trying to install a package globally (with -g) without providing permissions. Supposing that you are on os with sudo, try call

```
sudo npm install -g skpm
```

or, if you don't want it global

```
npm install skpm
```

Comment: See, what's funny is that I get these errors after I do the sudo command while installing. Those errors above were after doing your `sudo npm install -g skpm` - this didn't work.

Comment: oh, I see! can you check if already exists a folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/skpm/`? and, if yes, check the folder permissions or delete it before trying again

Comment: It looks like skpm doesn't exist. That's incredibly strange because it doesn't throw that error...

Comment: Well then try change the owner of the npm default folder with `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}` This changes the permissions of the sub-folders used by npm and some other tools (lib/node_modules, bin, and share)